# iOS first UICollectionViewCell image not loading ONLY after using constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Without constraints my UICollectionViewCells load immediately without any problems at all. When I put constraints on in storyboard so the image view is horizontal and vertically centered to the cell, the first image cell does not load.  I have to scroll a few times and then back to the beginning for the first image cell to show.  Take the constraints off and it goes back to working perfectly fine.

I thought maybe the images weren't getting loaded in time but that doesn't appear to be the case.

What am I missing?

I can put in some code but it is a pretty standard UICollectionView with custom cell inside ViewController.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell setImageName:imageName];

    [cell updateCell]; 
    return cell;

}



    -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return self.collectionView.frame.size;
    }
```

EDIT:
I just removed the navigation bar and the first 2 images were loading behind the nav bar. They are loading in the size of the default prototype CollectionViewCell. Once I scroll away and back to it, it is the expected size.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't put in constraints, IB automatically puts in constraints for you that give you an absolute position and size based on the frame in the storyboard.  Chances are good that the constraints you're adding are not doing what you think they are.

Comment: That is what I thought might be the case however, this is a horizontal collection view that is paging one cell at a time.  Every subsequent cell is doing exactly what I expect it to do and when I page back to the first cell, it is exactly where I expect it to be and the entire collection now performs exactly as it should.

Comment: Additionally, while the UIImage on the cell is not loading, the cell itself is loading (I made it another color to check) and it is exactly where it should be.  Seems like the constraints are messing up how the image loads initially.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I meant when I said the constraints aren't what doing what you think they are.  If you're only constraining the position and not the size, that might be your problem depending on your imagine and when you set it.

Comment: Right but why would that cause just the first and sometimes the second image to not load initially (or as your suggesting potentially off screen) but the following images load fine and then when I go swipe back to the first images they are where they should be.  Wouldn't the constraints be consistent?

Comment: Ok so I just removed the navigation bar and the first 2 images were loading behind the nav bar.  They are loading in the size of the default prototype CollectionViewCell.  Once I scroll away and back to it, it is the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [cell layoutIfNeeded]; right before return cell in cellforitematindexpath fixed it